# .NET Core API Tests with multiple authentication schemes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm the process of developing an application, which supports two different authentication schemes.

- A cookie based scheme used for login with username/password credentials. Upon authentication, the SPA will redirect to my authentication server and the user will perform the authentication there. (So no ResourceOwner/Password Grant flow).
- A Jwt based scheme used for external IdP authentication, I'm supporting Facebook authentication (For mobile apps) and guards /api/api2.

The server is monolith server, where the IdP and resource server are gathered as one. I'm using IdentityServer4 as authentication framework.

My code is inspired of the IS4 demo project:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Demo/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4Demo/Quickstart/Account/ExternalController.cs

I've the following clients configured both using the Code flow as Grant types:

```
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "mobileclient",
                ClientName = "Client 1",
                ClientSecrets = {new Secret("secret".Sha256())},
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                AllowedScopes = {"openid", "profile", "email"},
                RequireConsent = false,
                RequirePkce = true,
                AccessTokenLifetime = 3600,
                RequireClientSecret = false,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
                RedirectUris = {"http://localhost:54362/"},
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = {"https://notused"},
            },
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "adminclient",
                ClientName = "Client 2",
                ClientSecrets = {new Secret("secret".Sha256())},
                RequireConsent = false,
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                RequirePkce = true,
                RequireClientSecret = false,
                AllowedScopes = {"openid", "profile", "email"},
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
                RedirectUris = {"http://localhost:4200/auth-callback"},
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = {"http://localhost:5000/Account/Login"},
            },
```

I would like to create integration tests of my APIs, but I'm struggling to find a good approach/set of principles on how I should conduct tests of requests to my APIs, using both authentication schemes.

I'm using the WebApplicationFactory class and according to the documentation from Microsoft, 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#mock-authentication, they suggest that I should mock the authentication handler with some random values, but then I wouldn't be testing my original authentication logic, which is the intention of API tests.

So I would like to hear, if anybody has some good advice on:

- How to issue a JWT based on authentication using the external IdP (Facebook) for testing API 1 (Client 1)?
- How to set an authentication cookie used for testing API 2 (Client 2)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It just so happens that I made an article related to this a few days ago: https://joonasw.net/view/testing-azure-ad-protected-apis-part-3-automated-integration-tests. It's based on AAD, but it uses JWTs similarly. There I used credentials to get AAD tokens for testing. Not sure if this approach will work for Facebook.

Comment: Great article, but that would require me to have a fictional user at Facebook and some UI testing for handling the inputs at their prompt, which I would like to avoid. I'm not sure they support acquiring tokens by sending credentials over the wire. I appreciate your input :)